Dynamically Change Highlight.js Theme with Button Toggle (Light/Dark Mode)
I'm using the highlight.js library to display code snippets on my webpage. I'd like to add a button that allows users to switch between light and dark themes for the code snippets. Ideally, clicking the button should dynamically change the CSS theme file linked to highlight.js, transitioning the code snippet's appearance from light to dark or vice versa.
I've implemented the following code using JavaScript to achieve this:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>highlight.js</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" id="theme-link" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/11.9.0/styles/default.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/11.9.0/highlight.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/11.9.0/languages/go.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        hljs.highlightAll();

        var currentTheme = "light";
        function toggleTheme() {
            var themeLink = document.getElementById("theme-link");
            if(currentTheme === "light"){
                themeLink.href = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/11.9.0/styles/tomorrow-night-blue.css";
                currentTheme = "dark";
            } else {
                themeLink.href = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/11.9.0/styles/default.min.css";
                currentTheme = "light";
            }
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <pre>
        <code class="language-python">
            print("Hello World!");
        </code>
    </pre>
    
    <pre>
        <code class="language-python">
            print("Hello World!");
        </code>
    </pre>
    <button onclick="toggleTheme()">Toggle theme</button>
</body>
</html>

This code seems to work, but Are there any alternative or more efficient ways to achieve the same functionality?
I'd appreciate any insights or suggestions from the community!

Does this answer your question? how to create a "light and dark" functioning button using JS?

You have to to re-highlight the code with a different theme.

In Highcharts options you can conditionally set the colors like this:
chart: {
        type: 'column',
        backgroundColor: isDarkMode ? '#fff' : '#000',
        ...
}

and when theme button is clicked, create a new highchart and replace it:
function toggleTheme() {
  isDarkMode = !isDarkMode;
  Highcharts.chart(containerId, {
      credits: {
        enabled: false
      },
      chart: {
            type: 'column',
            backgroundColor: isDarkMode ? '#fff' : '#000',
            ...
            }
    }
}

The way you use Highchart may vary, but the concept is the same.
